# Angular с Spring Boot, node_modules appers empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, angular

Делаю в точности по https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web

> npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.4

потом сделал

> ng new angularclient

далее хочу сделать

> ng generate class user

но пишет

> node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`

почему и как пофиксить? ввожу npm install

> npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\korzh\Programming\Java\Study\Spring\angular-spring\package.json'
>   npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
>   npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\korzh\Programming\Java\Study\Spring\angular-spring\package.json'
>   npm WARN angular-spring No description
>   npm WARN angular-spring No repository field.
>   npm WARN angular-spring No README data
>   npm WARN angular-spring No license field.
>
> up to date in 2.656s
>
> found 0 vulnerabilities

так как уже в папке myproject -> angularclient -> node_modules существует.

структура проэкта

-.idea

-.mvn

-angularclient

-src

package-lock.json

pom.xml

пофиксил.

Теперь другая ошибка!

> Port 4200 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.

пишу ng serve --open --port 4201, тажа ошибка.

в cmd -> netstat нет порта 4200. Что делать?

если важно node version - v10.15.1

Answer (score 0):

Понял, нужно cd angularclient, так как там node_modules